# Alternatives to GCP / AWS / Azure

Tags: machine-learning, gpu, cloud-computing

Can anyone recommend an alternative to the big 3 cloud computing alternatives? I know they're the best but I found them overly complicated because they cater to massive enterprises. The amount of set up required just to get an instance running is too much.

I am looking for a multi GPU cloud offering which offers RAPIDS pre-installed. I see that Blazing SQL will have an offering soon, does anyone know of anything else that I could use in the mean time?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Paperspace Gradient](https://console.paperspace.com/signup?R=N5PXPJ5) to train my models. It provides all kinds of CPU and GPU machines, automated workflows and deployment with github integration. Setup might be confusing at first, but it is pretty well documented. It also has RAPIDS as a preconfigured template.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Linode:  https://www.linode.com/

Here's Linode's GPU service:  https://www.linode.com/products/gpu/